# Copy columns between two tables with different number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel file, I have two sheets with one table in each.

My goal is to go through my table in Sheet2 and copy/paste the columns from that table to the one in Sheet1.

The table in Sheet1 has columns that the table in Sheet2 doesn't.

**Table I want to paste data to**
[image]

**Table I get data from**
[image]

I use an **If** to compare the headers from both tables.

If B2 in Sheet2 is the same as B2 in Sheet1, (I compare the headers).
Then the program copies the related column in Sheet2 to the right place in Sheet1.

The "Married? (Yes/No)" column in the blue table is not in the yellow one.
How can I ignore that column and go to the next one?

Comment: Is there anyone with an idea?

Comment: Please I need help I really can't find a way to do it. I've been trying with a VLOOKUP in my VBA code but it doesn't work when there are additional columns in a table :/

Comment: Maybe try to copy the table in Sheet1 to Sheet2, something like `With Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1): .Range.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2"): 
End With`. Then insert a column to the table in Sheet2 `With Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects(1): .ListColumns.Add Position:=3: .HeaderRowRange(1, 3).Value = "Married? Yes/No": End With`